# Proof that $1 \geq \sqrt{1-p} \cdot \sqrt{1-p+e}+\sqrt{p} \cdot \sqrt{p-e}$ with $0<p<1$ and $0<e<p$

Tags: probability, inequality, radicals, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Is there a way to prove that

$$
1 \geq \sqrt{1-p} \cdot \sqrt{1-p+e}+\sqrt{p} \cdot \sqrt{p-e} \\
\leftrightarrow \sqrt{1-p} \cdot \sqrt{1-p}+\sqrt{p} \cdot \sqrt{p} \geq \sqrt{1-p} \cdot \sqrt{1-p+e}+\sqrt{p} \cdot \sqrt{p-e}
$$

with $0<p<1$ and $0<e<p$

I have been struggling on this all day, and I thought that one of you might have the answer? It may have to do with the concavity of the square-root function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after squaring two times and simplifications we get $$e^2>0$$ which is true.

Comment: You might want to elaborate a bit here. Squaring when there is addition involved can be a bit involved and takes care to do correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer - I did not think about squaring two times. It works perfectly, thanks again for saving my day !

Answer (score 1):

Try using Cauchy-Schwarz, see what you get from there. (Which is a result based on concavity, actually!)

Answer (score 1):

By C-S
$$\sqrt{(1-p)(1-p+e)}+\sqrt{p(p-e)}\leq\sqrt{(1-p+p)(1-p+e+p-e)}=1$$

Comment: Thank you very much - I had never heard about Cauchy-Schwarz theorem. I will document myself as it seems very handy in some situations. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Let $p=u^2$ and $p-e=v^2$, with $0\lt v\lt u\lt1$.  The inequality becomes

$$1\ge\sqrt{1-u^2}\sqrt{1-v^2}+uv$$

or

$$1-uv\ge\sqrt{1-u^2}\sqrt{1-v^2}$$

Since $1-uv\gt0$, this inequality is equivalent to

$$(1-uv)^2\ge(1-u^2)(1-v^2)$$

which simplifies to $u^2-2uv+v^2\ge0$, which holds since $u^2-2uv+v^2=(u-v)^2$.